# What is the correct way of linking local user account to federated user in WSO2 Identity server 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using **Google authenticator** (Oauth2 client) as an Identity provider in WSO2 5.10.0 . I created a **Service provider** which uses this google authenticator as **Federated authentication**.

When the user login for the first time using google credentials(gmail), I am able to make a local user by storing user in local user store through **Just-In-Time Provisioning** in Identity provider.
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-just-in-time-provisioning-for-an-identity-provider/

After the first login i assign roles to the local user manually.

Now when the user login again using federated(google) authentication, the roles that i provided to the local user does not get link with the federated user.

I read of Associating user account https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/associating-user-accounts/ using WSO2 user-portal

I tried adding

`[user.association]
enable_for_federated_users = true`

in **deployment.toml** . But when i open user-portal, i only see the option of linking local user account to another local user account.

I want to link user account with federated user such that when the federated user logs in, it takes the roles provided to the local user earlier and pass through the XACML role based policy.

XAMCL policy

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="role_based_login_policy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Description>This policy template provides ability to authorize users to a given service provider(defined by SP_NAME) in the authentication flow based on the roles of the user (defined by ROLE_1 and ROLE_2). Users who have at least one of the given roles, will be allowed and any others will be denied.</Description>
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">SP_Name</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/sp/sp-name" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/sp" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">authenticate</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/identity-action/action-name" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/identity-action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="permit_by_roles">
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:or">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny_others"></Rule>
</Policy>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the latest versions of the Identity Server (including 5.10.0), when the Just-In-Time provisioning is enabled, federated users and local users are associated automatically. So you don't need to enable the config you have mentioned and as the documentation has mentioned, it is not recommended.

So if you want to send the attributes of the local provisioned user to the application, you have to enable `Assert identity using mapped local subject identifier` configuration for the application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I checked the Assert identity box and added "admin" role to local user. But when i add an access control policy(PAP) to service provider and allow only admin to pass, still i get "Authentication attempt failed" when i authenticate. I've added xamcl policy in question now.

Comment: I tried the policy you have mentioned and it worked fine. I hope in the policy you have changed the SP_Name with the correct Application name. And also check if there are any other policies published that can interfere with this above policy. You can do so by disabling all the available policies in "PDP Policy View" section.

Comment: There are no other policies in PDP. Is there any chance that federated user is not getting linked with local user at the time of authorization?

Comment: i get the following log in "audit.log" file when "Authentication attempt fails"

TID: [-1234] [2020-05-14 14:41:25,377] [28ac7728-a35d-4f3f-80d0-03577fbe919a]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator : null | Action : Login | Target : ApplicationAuthenticationFramework | Data : { "ContextIdentifier" : "d33c81d7-3b2c-48b3-bb9b-76ba6aa9009d","ServiceProviderName" : "jenkins","RequestType" : "oidc","RelyingParty" : "u6wuuERE4btdlATfxglw0E_VhwMa","StepNo" : "0" } | Result : Failed

Comment: Have you seen any errors while provisioning the user?

Comment: No errors. Just one thing that i don't know, is the password of local user created. It is not same as federated user.

Comment: Definitely the password cannot be same since we are not getting the password from the federated identity provider. You have the option to prompt for password from user.

Comment: Yes. But that is not the issue. I am able to get the mapped roles in the final token received from wso2. Still i don't know how it is not able to pass through the policy. Maybe the authorization(policy) is happening before the user is mapped that is why it not getting local user details. Can you remember any other configurational changes?

Comment: I tried your exact policy (after changing the attribute value http://wso2.org/identity/sp/sp-name) and it worked fine for me. Authorization passed when the user had the role and failed when the user didn't have the role.